# Time based trigger on Formula Date field - what if the date changes on parent

Tags: formula-field, time-dependent-workflow

I have a formula field Campaign start date on the child object. 
Campaign start date = Campaign__r.StartDate
I have a time-based workflow that fires an email alert 10 days before this Campaign start date (Formula field).

Ex. Old Campaign StartDate = 10/20/2019
New Campaign StartDate = 10/30/2019

Question - If I change the start date on the Campaign record, will my workflow trigger before the changed Campaign start date? or will fire on old start date?

Please help.

Comment: If you would like to send an email based on the first (old) date value, you could have a checkbox field on the Child record that can be used as a Flag and set it to true once your Child record's start date field(formula field) is set with a value. And you could drive your email alert with this Flag.

Comment: Wait, you have a time based workflow on the Campaign Start Date on the child object? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought you couldn't define WF Rules on fomula fields (since they don't fire triggers and WFs) as they are calculated in real time? If the time based WF Rule is on the parent object instead, then it would be based on the new value (assuming it isn't being changed by another automated process such as a process builder or another WF Rule) if that is when it is firing. If it is already queued, that one would be based on the old value (it stores the time to run when it is queued).

Comment: The WF has criteria based on other fields. The time trigger is on the formula that is the Campaign start date. It does not update the time trigger if I change the parent start date.

Comment: unless there is DML on the child object, SFDC has no reason to re-evaluate it